# Background color isn't changing

Tags: compositing-nodes, color

I'm using the compositing to change the background color from black to pink, but after all the configuration, the background doesn't change the color, I have tried with different nodes and nothing. I even checked my first donut to see if I missed something, but everything looks good.
Is there something that I did wrong?
[image: The cupcake]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in render properties, turn on "transparent" then you will get:

[image]

[image]